# Calling javascript function in C# File

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am calling JavaScript function in C# file in Page Load method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleMaps(aLocations, aTitles, aSummary) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#test').GoogleMap(aLocations, aTitles, aSummary, {
                type: 3,
                zoom: 9
            });
        });
    }
</script>



</script>
```

and JavaScript code is

```
   function googleMaps(aLocations, aTitles, aSummary) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#test').GoogleMap(aLocations, aTitles, aSummary, {
                type: 3,
                zoom: 9
            });
        });
    }
```

I am getting this Error

```
caught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

Error is on following line

```
WebForm_InitCallback();var _spFormDigestRefreshInterval = 1440000;googleMaps('["keswick,cumbria,uk","grasmere,cumbria,uk","ambleside,cumbria,uk"]','["Keswick","Grasmere","Ambleside"]','["\u003cdiv class=\"ExternalClass1721CEC0617F42C887D068EA11963662\"\u003e\u003cfont class=\"ms-rteThemeForeColor-2-0\" face=\"Consolas\" size=\"2\"\u003e\u003cfont face=\"Consolas\" size=\"2\"\u003e\u003cfont face=\"Consolas\" size=\"2\"\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u0026lt;h3\u0026gt;Keswick\u0026lt;/h3\u0026gt;\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Keswick is a market town and civil parish within the Borough of Allerdale in Cumbria, England. It had a population of 4,984, according to the 2001 census.\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/font\u003e\u003c/font\u003e\u003c/font\u003e\u003c/div\u003e","\u003cdiv class=\"ExternalClass4AFD1E67B5374D86A656C26E69EEE124\"\u003e\u003cfont class=\"ms-rteThemeForeColor-2-0\" face=\"Consolas\" size=\"2\"\u003e\u003cfont face=\"Consolas\" size=\"2\"\u003e\u003cfont face=\"Consolas\" size=\"2\"\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u0026lt;h3\u0026gt;Grasmere\u0026lt;/h3\u0026gt;\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Grasmere is a village, and popular tourist destination, in the centre of the English Lake District. It takes its name from the adjacent lake of Grasmere, and is associated with the Lake Poets.\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/font\u003e\u003c/font\u003e\u003c/font\u003e\u003c/div\u003e","\u003cdiv class=\"ExternalClass8A0E058969E04AF59AF3B8FDACAB4576\"\u003e\u003cfont class=\"ms-rteThemeForeColor-2-0\" face=\"Consolas\" size=\"2\"\u003e\u003cfont face=\"Consolas\" size=\"2\"\u003e\u003cfont face=\"Consolas\" size=\"2\"\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u0026lt;h3\u0026gt;Ambleside\u0026lt;/h3\u0026gt;\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;Ambleside is a town in Cumbria, in North West England. Historically within the county of Westmorland, it is situated at the head of Windermere, Englands largest lake. The town is within the Lake District National Park.\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/font\u003e\u003c/font\u003e\u003c/font\u003e\u003c/div\u003e"]')function loadMDN2() { EnsureScript('MDN.js', typeof(loadFilterFn), null); }
```

Comment: Do you have your script tag in the markup set as `runat="server"`, if so remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var serializedResult1 = serializer.Serialize(getLocations());

        var serializedResult2 = serializer.Serialize(getTitles());
        var serializedResult3 = serializer.Serialize(getSummary());

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "googleMaps('" + serializedResult1 + "','" + serializedResult2 + "','" + serializedResult3 + "');", true);
```

Comment: Try to add a semicolon (changed my answer)

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted your JS into JSLint and got the same error, but when I moved the start of the function to the very top of the box in JSLint it went away. It says it expects function at column 1. Seems to suggest it might be worth bringing that function up to the very top and making it the first thing after your  tag - i.e. remove the white space preceding it. Have a go in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Does tidying it up make the "caught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function" go away? It does for me.